# How to connect Erlang in Windows to Ejabberd in Ubuntu?

Tags: intellij-idea, erlang, ejabberd

Not getting enough Packages related to Exmpp and not getting proper idea to connect Erlang and Ejabberd.

I tried to Connect Ejabberd Server running in Ubuntu To the Erlang in Windows.